# jQuery easing bug in Chrome: messy and leftover pixels

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-easing

I was working on this answer: [jQuery easing not working in my animate() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982313/jquery-easing-not-working-in-my-animate-call/26983858#26983858)

And noticed that sometimes when I hover over the square, some messy pixel lines remain visible.

This can be seen in the following jsFiddle:

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rtk3p98v/)

Sometimes when hovering over the square, the following (or similar) appears:

[image]

The lines around the square should not be there. I noticed that this bug only appears in Google Chrome. I am using version `38.0.2125.111 m`.

- Is this a known bug?
- Can anything be done to fix it?

Comment: Also, please let me know if you're not able to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also seeing the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These [rendering artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924986/animating-a-div-with-javascript-renders-artifacts-on-chrome) are fixed as of (at least) version `42.0.2311.90 m`.

In the new version, the artifacts do not appear anymore.